# Cross Domain Javascript with External Source

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

If a.com loaded b.com/b.js as an external source. What is the domain
 within j.js?  a.com, b.com or both?

Comment: ..........what? Where did `j.js` come from?

Comment: I believe `j.js` was supposed to be `b.js`.

Answer (score 1):

example.com can load any resource from any domain, but the code still has the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) so it can only talk to example.com. You do not get special rights by loading it 
from the other domain.

Imagine if linking to a file would all of the sudden allow cross domain talking. If that was the case, any site could link to a JS file of a bank, email provider, etc and be able to make Ajax calls behind the scenes. Not good!

One great reason for loading content from another domain is cookies are not sent, meaning smaller payload. Also if you are loading from a CDN, people may already have the files in their browser's cache so no download time!

If you are looking to make cross domain calls, you either need to look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control), or proxies.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs on the client side. If it looks at `window.location` it will see the *current* site - if that wasn't the case, all our JS from CDN's would point to the CDN's :)